# Contar la cantidad de registros que hay en mi BD ManyToMany

Tags: php, javascript, controller, symfony, doctrine2

no sé como explicarme para que me entiendan, incluso creo que hasta la pregunta la formulé mal, vamos a ver, necesito saber como (mejor pongo ejemplos), tengo una tabla reserva, y una tabla alimentos, su relación es de mucho a mucho, cuando por ejemplo renderizo las reservas que hay en la BD me queda así (los números son solo los id):

[image: Ejemplo de la lista de reservas]

O sea, tengo 3 reservas con esos alimentos, lo que quiero es como en mi controlador en Symfony, le digo que lo que necesito renderizar es:

[image: Lo que quiero]

Es decir, contar cuántas solicitudes de cada alimento tengo. Teniendo en cuenta las relaciones dichas anteriormente, cómo lo harían ustedes?...Muchas Gracias

Comment: Si en tu base de datos existe una relacion de muchos a muchos entre dos tablas deberas crear una tabla adicional. aqui te dejo un ejemplo (http://aulaclick-access.blogspot.com/2012/12/pantalla-de-ventas-en-access-2010-punto.html). Sin embargo teniendo en cuenta las relaciones que pones, yo haria un select a la tabla reserva para obtener lo registros de los alimentos, luego lo guardaria en un array y  con un bucle for buscaria los cada uno de los alimentos en el array.

Comment: Ya doctrine genera automaticamente esa tabla intermedia, por eso es que no me sale, intenté tambien de cierta forma eso q me dices y tampoco, me imagino Doctrine traiga algo más que no sepa para este tipo de problemas.

Answer (score 0):

Ya resolví, owww, Doctrine es un regalo ajaj, bueno, en el Repository hice esto:

```
  public function almacen($menu)
{
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $consulta = $em->createQueryBuilder();
    $consulta
        ->select('a')
        ->from('AdminBundle:Alimento', 'a')
        ->innerJoin('a.reserva', 'r')
        ->where('r.menu = :menu')
        ->setParameter('menu', $menu);
    // ->orderBy('a.nombre', 'ASC');
    return $consulta->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

En el controlador:

```
 /**
 * Lista todos los alimentos que hay que consumir en el menu para solicitarlo en el almacen.
 * @Route("/list", name="admin_almacen_list", condition="request.isXmlHttpRequest()")
 * @Method("GET")
 */
public function listAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $menu = $em->getRepository('AdminBundle:Menu')->findOneByFecha(new \DateTime('tomorrow'));
    $alimentos = $em->getRepository('AdminBundle:Reserva')->almacen($menu);
    return $this->render('AdminBundle:Almacen:list.html.twig', array(
        'alimentos' => $alimentos,
    ));
}
```

Y en la vista, la super sencillez:

```
{% for a in alimentos %}
{{ a }}...{{ a.reserva.count }}<br>
```

{% endfor %}

No era tan complejo, solo que a veces la desconcentración nos gana...